# Upsert only when two columns are conflicting?

Tags: postgresql, insert, upsert

Consider I have a table:

```
| A | B | C |
-------------
| 1 | 1 | X |
| 1 | 2 | Y |
| 2 | 1 | Z |
```

I want to write an upsert that only registers a conflict if the tuple in columns (A,B) is already in the table. So inserting (2, 2, K) is fine, (2, 1, L) would update the 3rd row from (2, 1, Z) to (2, 1, L).

Comment: Sure, just add a unique constraint to (A,B) and your insert statement would be something like INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ON (A,B) DO ...

Comment: Huh ... I saw a lot of questions regarding using two values INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ON (A,B) DO UPDATE ... having problems to actually do that. Thought there is a trick to it ...

Comment: What query have you tried?

Comment: None I first searched if using two values inside an on conflict constraint is valid and I got a lot of tutorials and stackoverflow posts that said "No you can't, that is invalid, what would happen if only one is in conflict, do this using a manual partial insert followed by an upsert manually" ... stuff like that.

Comment: Testing it out actually results in errors:

INSERT INTO table (A,B,C) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) ON CONFLICT (A,B) DO UPDATE SET C = $3;

Results in the error "there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification".

Comment: You need to create a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY` index for `A` and `B` combined.

Comment: Then ... add this as an answer?